# Integrating Facebook and Google Login to an existing REST API in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, omniauth

I have a Rest API written in Ruby on Rails which is having a regular SignUp and SignIn via a username and password. The SignUp and SignIn flows are currently handled through **"devise"** and **"simple_token_authentication"** Ruby Gems.

Now I need to integrate Facebook and Google Login to the existing SignUp and SignIn flows. Therefore, I'm looking for a recommendation to implement this easily.

I have already done some research and found, that I could use Koala for Facebook integration and I personally feel like Koala is a heavy Gem only to handle Facebook Login.

Would you recommend using it or does anyone else have an alternative approach. Or even writing a custom code to validate the Facebook access token in the server end sending back the application specific authentication token back to the client would be better.

PS : Is there a possibility of using the Omniauthable module in Devise to authenticate Facebook and Google users via the REST API.

Comment: Couldn't you just use omniauth? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Is there a way that we can validate the FB or Google access token usign the Omniauth? For the Web Applications we can leverage the Omniauthable module.